# Undefined Queryset with Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django-templates

here is views.py

```
if request.is_ajax():
        minpricestore = list(StoreProduct.objects.filter(product__id=productobj).values_list('store__StoreName' , flat=True).annotate(Min('price')))
        print minpricestore
        minprice = list(StoreProduct.objects.filter(product__id=productobj).values_list('price' , flat=True).annotate(Min('price')).order_by('price'))
        print minprice
        minId =  list(StoreProduct.objects.filter(product__id=productobj).values_list('store__id' , flat=True).annotate(Min('price')).order_by('price'))
        print minId

        data = {
        'minpricestore' : minpricestore , 
        'minprice' : minprice , 
        'minId' : minId
        }

        JsonResponse(data)
```

here is the ajax script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function sendProduct(event, productId) {
        event.preventDefault();   
        var data = { productId : productId };
        // Send productId as query param of url
        $.ajax({        
            type: "GET",
            url: "{{instance.get_absolute_url}}",
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data.minprice)
            },
            error: function(response, error) {
                alert(error);  
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

here is the queryset

```
minpricestore : [u'z store']
minprice: [1999]
minId:[1]
```

when i console.log it says undefined

ajax is working fine but unable to display the queryset.I get undefined when using alert.what can i do to to display the above queryset? Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you do console.log(data)

Comment: console.log returns some html

Comment: What is the html kindly update your question with that html

Comment: then parse the data first before getting the value.

Comment: it says undefined when i console.log(data.minprice)

Answer (score 0):

Add the dataType open in Ajax call

```
dataType: "json",
```